# TFS Build 2015 - using custom variables in label format

Tags: tfs, msbuild

TFS Build allows to define a label format in "repository" tab in build definition. I can define custom variables in "variables" tab and use them in label format definition. But is there any possibility to change a value of such custom variable in batch script in custom build step? Or maybe in some other type of a build step? I can get a value of such variable in a batch script, but any changes are ignored (though "Modify Environment" checkbox is set). Is there any possibility to use a value calculated during a build process as a part of a label format?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's mean of other type of a build step in your question? Could you give an example?

Comment: I use powershell in order to change a value of the custom variable in powershell:
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ProductVersionNumber;]$productVersion".

It works, but only initial value goes into the label. It seems that the format is evaluated at the very beginning of the build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be. There is no much difference with the  custom variable in  "variables" tab  and custom variable in batch script in custom build step.

However, please note **not every  custom variable can be used as a part of a lable format**. Please double check this.

> Some build variables might yield a value that is **not a valid label**.
>   For example variables such as `$(Build.RequestedFor)` and
>   `Build.DefinitionName` can contain white space. If the value contains
>   white space, the tag is not created.

---

*Update from OP*： As a workaround, with `build.updatebuildnumber` you could update a build number and then use `$(build.buildNumber)` in label format.

Comment: Using a custom variable in label did not help (updated value was not used, only initial value), but with build.updatebuildnumber i could update a build number and then use $(build.buildNumber) in label format.

Comment: I would like to confirm that custom variable value is calculated for a label when the build starts. And it is not affected by powershell scripts later. So "it should be" but "it does not". However you are absolutely right: using `Write-Host ("##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$env:versionFromFile")` it is possible to update `$(build.buildNumber)` to the custom `$(versionFromFile)` variable value that was set in the previous powershell script in the pipeline. Source label uses updated `$(build.buildNumber)` value.